# SQL: select all rows if parameter is null, else only select matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, isnull

I have a variable coming into a stored procedure. This variable can either have a value or be null.

- If the variable is null, I need to select all the rows in the table (some with NULL values, some with actual data).
- If the variable is not null, I only need to select the rows where the variable matches a column.

I created this conditional statement to help explain what I would like to achieve:

```
if 

@status is null, select all the rows (rows with NULL for table.status, and rows with actual data for table.status)

else

select the rows where @status equals table.status
```

This is what I came up with (well one of them):

```
WHERE 
   book.book_nme LIKE @search_input AND
   book.book_desc LIKE @search_input AND 
   (book.author LIKE ISNULL(@author, book.author)) AND
   (bookStatus.status_desc LIKE ISNULL(@status, bookStatus.status_desc))
```

The only problem is that if `bookStatus.status_desc` is NULL, then it will not select that row (when @status is null)

I'm so confused, I tried looking up Coalesce too which seemed to prioritize the values, but ... I don't know what to do.

Should I just create a huge CASE in the stored procedure and have two select statements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE  book.book_nme LIKE @search_input AND
book.book_desc LIKE @search_input AND 
(@author IS NULL OR book.author LIKE @author) AND
(@status IS NULL OR bookStatus.status_desc LIKE @status) ...
```

**Update**
Added both conditions, for `@author` and `@status`

Comment: I spent like an hour and a half on this, I feel so dumb.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize `@status` is the variable you are interested in, not `@author`.Fixing...

Comment: I needed to do it for both status and author, so it really doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

If you think it about your description it breaks down as:

- Return all rows when @status is null
- Otherwise return rows that match @status.

You can express the last line of your sql to match this like this:

```
(@status is null OR bookStatus.status_desc LIKE @status)
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this:

WHERE fieldname = ISNULL(@parameter, fieldname)

Hope this helps
Roger

Answer (score 0):

`where(field1 like isnull(@parameter,field1))`

If the paramater is null will retrieve all data from field1
like

`select field from table1`

This works on sybase.